# How to bind keyboard shortcut to run command on selected file in linux?

Tags: linux, command, settings, system

I know how to set a keyboard command shortcut, that's easy, I just go to *Applications > Settings > Keyboard* and then click the *Application Shortcuts* tab within my Manjaro Linux system and set whatever command to whatever shortcut.

But how can I make it run that command on a selected file or selection of files?

Is there something I can change or add to the command to make it run on the file or files currently selected within my XFCE desktop environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would require to correlate your mouse position to your desktop and file-manager. Then you would need to have knowledge of the internal state. You then would need to display some GUI. This way of thinking in regards of programing is seriously wrong.

What you are looking for are context menu actions. So keep it that way.

You have files on your desktop or in the file-manager and can call user defined actions on one or more files. I think XFCE had something like Thunar. You may use caja wit `caja --no-desktop` and create some actions with `caja-actions-config-tool`. Gnome still has it, if you prefer Nautilus.